# Where is local javadoc for ControlsFX?

Tags: controlsfx

I'm new(ish) to Java/Netbeans/ControlsFX. I know about Javadoc and would like NetBeans to show me javadoc for ControlsFX. I see the online version of the docs for ControlsFX but that defeats (at least part of) the purpose of using an IDE? I know how to add the doc zip file in NetBeans but I don't see the doc file for ControlsFX.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Found this lately. [ControlFx java doc](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.controlsfx:controlsfx/8.40.10). You can manipulate the version number at the end of the url to get to page of any other version of the doc if it is in existence. Download the jar version on that page to use it locally controlsfx-*version*-javadoc.jar. Then you can add the jar in your netbeans Javafx project.